# TensorFlow trim values in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I perform the following in a TensorFlow tensor?

In matrix A: if A[i,j] > 1 then A[i,j] = 1

(in numpy I would do this: `A[A>1] = 1`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.minimum`, which does element-wise minimum calculation; By setting `y = 1`, values in `x` will be clipped with the maximum of `1`:

```
A = tf.constant([-1, 0, 1, 3, 4])

A_clipped = tf.minimum(A, 1)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
A_clipped.eval()
# array([-1,  0,  1,  1,  1], dtype=int32)
```

---

Another option is use `tf.where` to set values:

```
tf.where(A > 1, tf.constant(1, shape=A.shape), A).eval()
# array([-1,  0,  1,  1,  1], dtype=int32)
```

---

If you need to update Variable `A`:

```
A = tf.Variable([-1, 0, 1, 3, 4])
​
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.assign(A, tf.minimum(A, 1)).eval()

A.eval()
# array([-1,  0,  1,  1,  1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Your answer lacks of the assignment part. Isn't it?

Comment: Both of these two approaches create new tensors instead of modifying  `A` directly, so I guess you don't `tf.assign` here?

Comment: I mean, OP is asking how to modify the input matrix A, not creating a new tensor from A.